# Angular Manually Typed Path "vs" Router Link

Tags: angular

When I manually type in a path to a component (/whatever) my entire site reloads (all initial root service calls are made), but when I use a router link  to the same component e.g.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/whatever']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
```

Only the calls required for the services of that component are made

Is there something I can do to make manually typed paths work like a routerLink?

Comment: No. there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Perhaps maybe rethink your design, do you really need to load all those data when the site reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The only way to change the url with out loading a page is the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) which angular router uses under the hood. If user hits enter in the address bar or clicks an anchor tag with an href it will always load a resource in the browser. To mitigate the overhead of initializing all of the services and initial components many SPA frameworks offer SSR (server side rendering) where some of the initialization can be done server side before the page (re)loads. If its lots of data loading at init you could look into caching or local store, if there are a lot of assets (css, images) you could look into service worker (offline app).

Edit:
Lazy loading anything you don't need right away can also reduce the init overhead.